# Grouped shapes not removed in MS Word using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove shapes from word document using this code:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shp in word.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{
    shp.Delete();
}

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ilshp in word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes)
{
    if (ilshp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
    {
        ilshp.Delete();
    }
}
```

It's working fine, but some grouped shapes like flow charts are not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shapes` are grouped in other `Shapes` being an item in the `GroupItems` collection.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

void DeleteShape(Word.Shape shp)
{
    try
    {
        if (shp != null)
        {
            if ((int)shp.Type == 6  /* MsoShapeType.msoGroup */)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Deleting shape group {shp.Name} with {shp.GroupItems.Count} items");

                //  it is not necessary to delete the group member shapes
            }

            Debug.WriteLine($"Deleting shape {shp.Name}");
            shp.Delete();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

It does not work to delete all shapes simply traversing the collection of shapes.

```
var word = new Word.Application();
var doc = word.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\doc1.docx");

//  avoid problems deleting in current collection
var list = new List<Word.Shape>();
foreach(Word.Shape shape in word.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{
    list.Add(shape);
}

foreach (Word.Shape shape in list)
{
    DeleteShape(shape);
}
```

The collection gets corrupted if the current `Shape` item is deleted. You can either traverse the collection in reverse direction or copy the `Shape` items into another collection.